# Generate pure text using php

Tags: php, string

I'm using a service that I end up with a generated string. Strings are usually like:

```
Hello &nbsp; Mr &nbsp; John Doe, you are now registered \t.
Hello &nbsb; Mr &nbsp; John Doe, your phone number is &nbsb; 555-555-555 &nbs; \n
```

I need to remove all html entities and all \t and \n and etc.

I can use `html_entity_decode`, to remove none breaking spaces, and use `str_replace` for removing `\t` or `\n`, but is there a more general way? some thing that makes you sure nothing but alphabet characters exist in the string  (some string that doesn't contain codes).

Comment: alphabet characters depends on your definition of alphabet. technically &nbsp are five alphabet characters.

Comment: @Gordon I mean a string that does not include any code.

Comment: try using heredoc syntax

Comment: You can use the nl2br function to turn \n to br if you want to keep the line break

Comment: Is that real input? Do you mean that you have damaged HTML entities mixed with PHP escape sequences?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález If i be more specific, I have a text wrapped in a <p> tag.  and texts usually contain html special characters and \t or \n and so on... this text will be showed perfect on the screen but the problem is, this text will be sent as text message for some users too. I dont want user to see &nbsp or \t  in the text message. i want to cut every code out of the string before sending it as a text message.

Comment: You don't understand his point.  Your example is full of errors.  If it is not real data, then this is not a complete example.   &nbsp, $nbsb and &nbs are all invalid.  A valid space entity is '&nbsp;'  People require REAL sample strings, not something you made up and typed in incorrectly.

Comment: html_entity_decode does not remove entities.  It converts them.  You said you want to remove them, and you could use html_entity_decode.  That is an incorrect assumption.  Do you really want to remove them all, or actually just convert them to text?

Comment: @gview You're completely right, sorry about the mistakes, I fixed them now. Yes I do want to remove them. because this text is going to be sent as a text message.

Comment: You have a good complete answer to try out.  I'm not sure you want to remove them.  If you have Mr&nbsp;Smith, and you remove the &nbsp; then you get a screwed up string: MrSmith when it should be Mr Smith.  If you have 'He said &quot;Hi&quot;, then you don't get 'He said "Hi"'.  For me that is mangling the original input.  Take a look at Alvaro's answer.  If you want to extraneous space that is something else you can use the techniques he provided which uses a regex to remove extra spaces.

Answer (score 2):

If I understood your case correctly, you basically want to convert from HTML to plain text.

Depending on the complexity of your input and the robustness and accuracy needed, you have a couple of options:

- Use [strip_tags()](http://php.net/strip_tags) to remove HTML tags, [mb_convert_encoding()](http://php.net/mb_convert_encoding) with `HTML-ENTITIES` as source encoding to decode entities and either [strtr()](http://php.net/strtr) or [preg_replace()](http://php.net/preg_replace) to make any additional replacement:

  ```
  $html = "<p>Hello &nbsp; Mr &nbsp; John Doe, you are now registered.
      Hello &nbsp; Mr &nbsp; John Doe, your phone number is &nbsp; 555-555-555 &nbsp;
      Test: &euro;/&eacute;</p>";

  $plain_text = $html;
  $plain_text = strip_tags($plain_text);
  $plain_text = mb_convert_encoding($plain_text, 'UTF-8', 'HTML-ENTITIES');
  $plain_text = strtr($plain_text, [
      "\t" => ' ',
      "\r" => ' ',
      "\n" => ' ',
  ]);
  $plain_text = preg_replace('/\s+/u', ' ', $plain_text);

  var_dump($html, $plain_text);
  ```
- Use a proper DOM parser, plus maybe `preg_replace()` for further tweaking:

  ```
  $html = "<p>Hello &nbsp; Mr &nbsp; John Doe, you are now registered.
      Hello &nbsp; Mr &nbsp; John Doe, your phone number is &nbsp; 555-555-555 &nbsp;
      Test: &euro;/&eacute;</p>";

  $dom = new DOMDocument();
  libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
  $dom->loadHTML($html);
  libxml_use_internal_errors(false);
  $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

  $plain_text = '';
  foreach ($xpath->query('//text()') as $textNode) {
      $plain_text .= $textNode->nodeValue;
  }
  $plain_text = preg_replace('/\s+/u', ' ', $plain_text);

  var_dump($html, $plain_text);
  ```

Both solutions should print something like this:

```
string(169) "<p>Hello &nbsp; Mr &nbsp; John Doe, you are now registered.
    Hello &nbsp; Mr &nbsp; John Doe, your phone number is &nbsp; 555-555-555 &nbsp;
    Test: &euro;/&eacute;</p>"
string(107) "Hello Mr John Doe, you are now registered. Hello Mr John Doe, your phone number is 555-555-555 Test: €/é"
```